# How to set the TFS NuGet Packager destination folder?

Tags: tfs, build, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

I added I new build step in TFS 2017 to pack my DLL into a nuspec (**NuGet Packager**).
My problem is that I can't manage to set the destination folder.

The description of the "**Package Folder**" is

> Folder where packages will be created. If empty, packages will be
>   created alongside the csproj or nuspec file.

[image]

When I leave this field empty **I expect it to be created in "$/MyProject/Common/"** as described in the information. But it's keep creating it in the builder agent root folder. and adding **"-OutputDirectory "C:_work\24\s""** even if I'm writting another folder in the package folder.

What am I doing wring here?
Is there a better way to pack and publish nuget for every release build in TFS?

NuGet Packager Log:

```
2017-04-02T15:01:51.3457383Z Set workingFolder to default: C:\agent\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.72
2017-04-02T15:01:51.3769893Z Executing the powershell script: C:\agent\tasks\NuGetPackager\0.1.72\NuGetPackager.ps1
2017-04-02T15:01:51.6426327Z C:\agent\agent\worker\tools\NuGet.exe pack "C:\_work\24\s\Common\Common.nuspec" -OutputDirectory "C:\_work\24\s" -version 1.0.17092.08
2017-04-02T15:01:52.0332823Z Attempting to build package from 'Common.nuspec'.
2017-04-02T15:01:52.1895494Z Successfully created package 'C:\_work\24\s\Common.1.0.17092.08.nupkg'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just specify the folder where you want to put the packages.

> **[Package Folder](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/package/nuget-packager)**
>
> Specify the folder where you want to put the packages. You can use a
>   variable such as `$(Build.StagingDirectory)\packages`

[image]

---

**Update**

When you leave the folder empty, it will auto  AddParameter of outputdir= builder agent root folder. When you enter `$/MyProject/Common` it will create the folder base on `builder agent root folder/$/MyProject/Common`

[image]

According to the powershell script located at  `C:\agent\tasks\NuGetPackager\xxx\NuGetPackager.ps1`

```
 $argsPack = "pack `"$fileToPackage`" -OutputDirectory `"$outputdir`" -Properties $buildProps";
```

So it will definitely put it in the agent root folder. Back to the description:

> If you leave it empty, the package will be created in the same
>   directory that contains the .csproj or .nuspec file.

Not sure **the same directory** means be **the same folder level** or not. However the *alongside* seems mean the same folder level.

You could submit a bug either in [GITHub-VSTS Tasks](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues) or  [Develop Community-Team Services](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) both will get quick response by TFS develop team.

Comment: Eventually I did manage to directly use the package folder path with a server path such as  $/MyProject/Common. 
But the problem is when I leave it empty it's always put it in the agent root folder. For example my the path to the nuspec is to directly use the package folder path with a server path such as  $/MyProject/Common/dir_a/dir_b/mynu.nuspec  --> the nupkg will be created in "$" (C:_work)  and not in "$/MyProject/Common/dir_a/dir_b" as expected.

Comment: @AviramFireberger After go through more details, got the same result as you.  Not sure the same directory means be the same folder level or not. Suggest you to submit a bug report in github or develop community. More details please see my update reply.

Comment: Great, Thanks for the detailed answer

Comment: I opened a report in the developer community:   https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39529/tfs-nuget-packager-destination-folder-does-not-wor.html